# how to add multiple grids in custom module in magento 1.9 ?

Tags: magento-1.9

[image]

Getting this Error , can anyone suggest steps to add multiple grids ?

Comment: Error was due to changes made in etc/config.xml , just removed items from file and it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your snapshot, it seems that helper function is n not working in your module. To work it again you will need to disable the module from `app/etc/modules`. Pleae rename "Hello module".